# How do I implement a setOptions method for a Class ? Error: TypeError: this.setOptions is not a function

Tags: javascript

I got error js error Error: TypeError: this.setOptions is not a function, I have already set Implements: [Options],

```
var SessionKeeperWarning = new Class({
    Implements: [Options],
    options:{
        messagetype:'js',
        timeout:0,
        warning:0,
        strings:{},
        dimension:{'x':400,'y':300},
        keepalivelight:false,
        path:''
    },
    timer:false,
    expired:false,
    initialize: function(options) { 
        alert("Here");
        this.setOptions(options);
        this.setTimer();
    },
```

Comment: You don't have a `setOptions` function. `Implements:` doesn't do that for you. MooTools have a [useful reference](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class).

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I reviewed reference document, and I have defined function like setOptions:function(){ }, but what I have need to write code inside this function?

Comment: I have no idea. I would suggest rewriting this question to ask "How do I implement a setOptions method for a Class" or something, and including your current code instead of what's there now.